# How to drop tuple which has data less than average in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a bag with 3 field(id, name and post_num) and I want to drop tuple whose post_num is less than average post_num each name. For example, I have 4 data like below:

`1, Dav, 5
2, Dav, 6
3, Dav, 4
4, Ed, 1`

then 3rd data should by dropped because the average post_num for Dav is 5.

Can I do it without UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- ## Suppose you have
-- 1000,SMITH,123
-- 1001,JOHN,452
-- 1002,TWAIN,125
-- 1003,HARDY,124
-- 1004,CHILD,785
-- 1005,CHILD,639
-- 1006,DAVIS,89
-- 1007,DAVIS,173
-- 1008,MIKE,420
-- 1009,DENNIS,562
-- 1010, CHILD,638

###   Then try this on Pig CLI:

data = LOAD '/mnt/e_drive/temp/csdata.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, post_num:int);
-- data: {id: int,name: chararray,post_num: int}

grpData= GROUP data BY name;
-- grpData: {group: chararray,data: {(id: int,name: chararray,post_num: int)}}

avgData = foreach grpData generate FLATTEN(data), AVG(data.post_num) as avg_post_num;
--avgData: {data::id: int,data::name: chararray,data::post_num: int,avg_post_num: double}

filterData = filter avgData by  (double) data::post_num >= avg_post_num;
--filterData: {data::id: int,data::name: chararray,data::post_num: int,avg_post_num: double}

requiredData=  foreach filterData generate data::id as id, data::name as name, data::post_num as post_num;
--requiredData: {id: int,name: chararray,post_num: int}



-- TO Debug ---------------------
dump avgData;

-- (1001,JOHN,452,452.0)
-- (1008,MIKE,420,420.0)
-- (1010,CHILD,638,687.3333333333334)
-- (1005,CHILD,639,687.3333333333334)
-- (1004,CHILD,785,687.3333333333334)
-- (1007,DAVIS,173,131.0)
-- (1006,DAVIS,89,131.0)
-- (1003,HARDY,124,124.0)
-- (1000,SMITH,123,123.0)
-- (1002,TWAIN,125,125.0)
-- (1009,DENNIS,562,562.0)


dump requiredData;
--(1001,JOHN,452)
--(1008,MIKE,420)
--(1004,CHILD,785)
--(1007,DAVIS,173)
--(1003,HARDY,124)
--(1000,SMITH,123)
--(1002,TWAIN,125)
--(1009,DENNIS,562)
```

Comment: I think I may not express the question clearly. Every name has a average post_num. In your example, if I have a data 1010, CHILD,638, then it should be dropped because the average post_num for CHILD is 687 and its post_num is 638

Comment: that means you want to perform average by name. I have updated the answer accordingly, if still not covers the case then let me know.